# Calculating area of plant vegetation present in every Landsat image available using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have made this code that calculates the area of vegetation on a river in Zambia:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/741cffac115808359d219068860e4ced

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [28.272901906392413, -15.770509003775409],
  [28.272901906392413, -15.812135053950925],
  [28.431860341451006, -15.812135053950925],
  [28.431860341451006, -15.770509003775409]
]])

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1")
  .filterDate('1983-05-01', '2003-07-15')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 172))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 71))
  .select("B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")
  .median()
  
// Compute the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI).
var ndvi = s2.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
var ndviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
}

Map.centerObject(roi, 13)
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(roi), ndviVis, "NDVI")

var mean_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30
})

//Thresholding based mapping  
var waterbody = ndvi.lte(0)

var area = ndvi.gte(0.2).selfMask()
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).rename('Area').divide(1e5)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true,
  })

print('Area is:', area.get('Area'))
```

However, I need a way for it to calculate the area of vegetation present in every single Landsat image available. Currently, it only calculates mean area for whatever date you set it at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a median composite from your Landsat imagery, and calculate the vegetation area in that composite. Instead, you can map over the image collection, and calculate the vegetation area in each image.

Note that clouds in individual images will effect your vegetation area.

```
var ndviImagery = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1")
  .filterDate('1983-05-01', '2003-07-15')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 172))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 71))
  .map(toNDVI)
  
var areas = ndviImagery.map(toVegetationArea)
print('Areas:', areas.aggregate_array('area'))


function toNDVI(image) {
  return image
    .normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames()) // Keep image properties, like date
}


function toVegetationArea(ndvi) {
  var vegetation = ndvi.gte(0.2)
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .updateMask(vegetation)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: roi,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e9,
      bestEffort: true,
    })
    .getNumber('area')
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    area: area,
    date: ndvi.date() // You might need to know for which date an area represents?
  })
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e99f7f6e4ec04393ef1e1a77bc9b2bd4

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I do need to know the dates for each area, but it doesn't look like date: ndvi.date() shows me that. Also, how would I get rid of clouds? I only know of Sort(Cloud_Cover), but that just sorts from least cloudy to most cloudy and I need any images with significant cloud cover removed.